# Нужна помощь с парсером для ЕГЮРЛ

Tags: python, парсер, запрос

Есть сайт https://egrul.nalog.ru/index.html
Хочу написать парсер для выгрузки выписки от туда.

Сначала делается post запрос с параметром `query='ИНН'`
В ответ я получаю в JSON ключ типа: `"t":"C639546DE6364BFC462A39C02862A0B22F85F1E317B359D71395917F336D71BAA0236A6C60146CE8DA52DA53239A290DC8D49DCF99ECD6F42984FCB851DAF1702B970C938627ED122A7A66BEDCA70A09","captchaRequired":false}`

Далее судя по всему делается запрос:

> egrul.nalog.ru/search-result/{здесь подставить ранее
> полученное}?r=1627021393883&_=1627021393883

Вопрос именно в `r=1627021393883&_=1627021393883`, я как понимаю это время в UNIX формате. Время не текущее, там то ноябрь, то октябрь выдает. Не могу понять, откуда оно берется, где браузер его получает?
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: не проще сделать это с помощью API? https://api-fns.ru/api_help#section_vyp , тарифы и доступ - https://api-fns.ru/index

Comment: Да знаю. Мне важно сделать это бесплатно.

Comment: бесплатный тариф тоже имеется :), но можно и без API как оказалось

Answer (score 5, accepted):

этот параметр необязателен.

```
import requests

url = 'https://egrul.nalog.ru'
url_1 = 'https://egrul.nalog.ru/search-result/'
url_2 = 'https://egrul.nalog.ru/vyp-download/'
inn = 21..98

r = requests.post(url, data={'query': inn})
print(r.json()['t'])

r1 = requests.get(url_1 + r.json()['t'])
print(r1.json()['rows'][0]['n'])
print(r1.json()['rows'][0]['t'])

r2 = requests.get(url_2 + r1.json()['rows'][0]['t'])
with open(f'{r1.json()["rows"][0]["n"]}_{str(inn)}.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r2.content)
```

таким образом будет скачан pdf файл с именем "ФИО_ИНН"

UPD:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.get(url + '/index.html')
print(s.cookies)

r = s.post(url, data={'query': inn}, cookies=s.cookies)
print(r.json()['t'])

r1 = s.get(url_1 + r.json()['t'], cookies=s.cookies)
print(r1.json()['rows'][0]['n'])
print(r1.json()['rows'][0]['t'])

r2 = s.get(url_2 + r1.json()['rows'][0]['t'], cookies=s.cookies)
with open(f'{r1.json()["rows"][0]["n"]}_{str(inn)}.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r2.content)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ДмитрийАгафонов, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Обнаружил, что есть проблема при скачивании файла. Он скачивается, но не читается.

Comment: Страница возвращает ошибку почему-то

Comment: действительно, по какой-то причине возвращается ошибка, но проверил только что (15:04МСК) файл успешно сохраняется и открывается, может требуется добавить заголовки и/или куки в запрос

Comment: Да, если с браузера сначала скачать, и попробовать через код, то все ок, а если без браузера, то не работает. Видимо надо добавлять куки

Comment: как вариант попробуйте `s = requests.Session()` `r = s.post(...` и в `r1` укажите `cookies=r.cookies`

Comment: Все равно ошибка.
Ладно, буду разбираться, это уже тема для другого вопроса.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127842/discussion-between-violet-and--).

Comment: обновил ответ, проверьте

Comment: Все так же ошибка

Comment: Все, работает, надо было заголовок добавить