# Как скачать файлы по url при помощи python и библиотеки wget?

Tags: python, wget

Есть некий ресурс с pdf и doc файлами внутри. Нужно загрузить все эти файлы на локальную машину.
Файлы имеют следующую ссылку: https://site.ru/files/download_file и далее номер документа, например 1025 (https://site.ru/files/download_file/1025). Написал следующий код, но у меня не работает. Подскажите как починить мой кривой код. Спасибо.

```
import wget
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context #Вылетала ошибка сертификата, поэтому это здесь)

dir_url = '\\pdf'

def tets():
    url_num = 1024
    for i in range(10):
        url_num += i
        url = 'https://site.ru/files/download_file/{url_num}'
        wget.download(url, out=dir_url)
    print('Good')

tets()
```

На этом этапе выполнение кода просто "висит" без ошибок

Comment: можете привести реальную ссылку на ресурс? и почему не `requests`?

Comment: Violet, ссылку если только в личку. Только сейчас появилась задача скачать доки с ресурса и первое на что наткнулся это был wget.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1308008/234134 вот пример загрузки файла через `requests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все работает. Вы используете строку с подстановкой значения переменной, но не определяете ее как форматируемую.

Должно быть `url = f'https://site.ru/files/download_file/{url_num}'` или `url = 'https://site.ru/files/download_file/{}'.format(url_num)`

Прилагаю пример, где я качал через `wget` `pdf` с `mos.ru`

```
import wget
# import ssl

def tets():
    year = 2020
    url = f'https://www.mos.ru/upload/newsfeed/presspresentations/otchet_{year}.pdf'
    wget.download(url)
    print('Good')

tets()
```

Все работает и без установки `ssl` контекста